# Use 3 methods(Addition, Average, numberEvenOdd) in an array

Tags: java

I have an array named tab with several numbers

```
int[] tab = {1,3,4,2};
```

I have to create 3 methods:

1) the first addition() method

2) the second average() method

3) the third numberEvenOdd() method

My goal : I have to calculate the average of the odd numbers in the array by using my 3 methods.

Here is my `addition()` method

```
public static int addition(int[] tab){
            int sum = 0;
            for(int i=0;i<tab.length;i++){
                sum += tab[i];
            }
            return sum;
        }
```

Then, my `average()` method

```
public static double averages(int[] tab){
            return (double) addition(tab) / tab.length;
}
```

And my `numberOddEven()` method

```
public static int numberOddAdd(int[] tab, boolean value){
    int parity = 0;
    if(! value){
        parity = 1;
     }

    int n = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<tab.length;i++){
         if(tab[i] % 2 == parity){
             n += tab[i];
         }
     }
    return n;
    }
```

In my print, I have a problem in the syntax ?

I have tried this

```
System.out.println(averages(numberOddEven(tableau1, false));
```

My error message is -> `incompatible types: int cannot be converted to int` ?

Comment: `int` cannot be converted to `int[]` (read the error next time). `averages` takes an `int[]` while `numberOddAdd` returns a single `int`. `int` is not an `int[]`.

Comment: It seems that you have at least three versions of the third method. The first is called `numberEvenOdd()`, the second is called `numberOddEven()` and your example is `numberOddAdd()`. What exactly is it that this third method is supposed to do? Assuming it is supposed to retrieve the 1st, 3rd, 5th... (or 2nd, 4th, 6th...) elements from the array `int [] tab` then the third method would be declared as `public static int [] numberOddEven(...` and would presumably return a new array of int approximately half the size of the original.